# How to get docky to show window panels?

Tags: 18.04, budgie, docky

I've looked around all day to get an answer and it seems like a lot of people don't like window panels or something. or maybe it's not possible but I really need window panels. i sometimes have a lot of file windows open for easy drag and drop. can someone just tell me if it's possible to get window panels for docky on Budgie.